# How can I get selected value from a list-grop with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, list, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to take some value (text and ID) from a selected value on a list-grop:

```
<div class="list-group col-lg-10" >             
    <a href="#" id="id1" class="list-group-item col-lg-6">Example 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="id2" class="list-group-item col-lg-6">Example 2</a>     
</div>
```

I want to take them only after click on a button. How can I get the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

```js
StoreValue = []; //Declare array
$(".list-group a").click(function(){
    StoreValue = []; //clear array
    StoreValue.push($(this).attr("id")); //add id to array
    StoreValue.push($(this).text()); // add text to array
})
 $(".button").click(function(){
    alert(StoreValue[0] + " " + StoreValue[1])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group col-lg-10" >             
    <a href="#" id="id1" class="list-group-item col-lg-6">Example 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="id2" class="list-group-item col-lg-6">Example 2</a>     
</div>
<div class="button">Click here</div>
```

Comment: I don't want all list values but only what I selected.

Comment: The click needs to works only on button. I thought about this method: store the value after the click on <a> tag and then using it after the click on button.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('a').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    var text = $(this).html()


    console.log(id)
    console.log(text)
})

$('#get').click(function () {
    var id1 = $('#id1').attr('id')
    var text1 = $('#id1').html()

    var id2 = $('#id2').attr('id')
    var text2 = $('#id2').html()
    console.log(id1)
    console.log(text1)
    console.log(id2)
    console.log(text2)
})
```

create an event click and inside get the id using `$(this).attr('id')` and the text using `$(this).html()`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f50L6mpa/1/)